# Python- Variable Won't Subtract?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a simple question and answer game in Python (version 3.3.2), but can't figure out how to make an expression work. The "health" and "oppHealth" variables seen below will not change as the program runs, or at least the string display won't show them changing. Source code:

```
import time

#Variables
health = 30
oppHealth = 30
playStr = str(health)
oppStr = str(oppHealth)

def startBattle():
    print()
    print('You face off against your opponent.')
    print()
    print("Your health is " + playStr + ".")
    print("Your opponent's health is " + oppStr + ".")
    time.sleep(2)
    print()
    print('The opponent attacks with Fire!')
    time.sleep(2)
    print()
    attack = input('How do you counter? Fire, Water, Electricity, or Ice?')
    if attack == ('Fire'):
        print("You're evenly matched! No damage is done!")
        time.sleep(3)
        startBattle()
    elif attack == ('Water'):
        print("Water beats fire! Your opponent takes 5 damage!")
        oppHealth - 5
        time.sleep(3)
        startBattle()
    elif attack == ('Electricity'):
        print("You both damage each other!")
        health - 5
        oppHealth - 5
        time.sleep(3)
        startBattle()
    elif attack == ('Ice'):
        print("Fire beats ice! You take 5 damage.")
        health - 5
        time.sleep(3)
        startBattle()

startBattle()
```

I simply want to make the appropriate health variables decrease by 5- and for the health displaying strings to reflect the change- every time a battle occurs. If anyone can help me with this, I'd greatly appreciate it. Please let me know if I've excluded any information that might help you help me.

Answer (score 4):

the lines

```
health - 5
oppHealth - 5
```

and similar, do not actually modify anything, to save the subtraction back in the variables, use the `-=` operator instead

```
health -= 5
```

or you can also say

```
health = health - 5
```

The above two examples both achieve the same result.  When you just say `health - 5` you don't actually save it anywhere.

In addition to this you will need to specify `global` at the top of your function to modify these values or you will get an error.

```
def startBattle():
    global health
    global oppHealth
    # ... rest of function
```

Also you don't need the `playStr` and `oppStr` variables, you can print the numeric values like this:

```
print(f"Your health is {health}.")
print(f"Your opponent's health is {oppHealth}.")
```

---

These don't really need to be global at all though, they can be within the function, sitting in a loop, my version of your program would be this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time


def startBattle():
    # set initial values of healths
    health = 30
    oppHealth = 30
    print('You face off against your opponent.', end='\n\n')
    while health > 0 and oppHealth > 0: # loop until someone's health is 0
        print(f"Your health is {health}.")
        print(f"Your opponent's health is {oppHealth}.", end='\n\n')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('The opponent attacks with Fire!', end='\n\n')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('How do you counter? Fire, Water, Electricity, or Ice?')
        attack = input('>> ').strip().lower()
        if attack == 'fire':
            print("You're evenly matched! No damage is done!")
        elif attack == 'water':
            print("Water beats fire! Your opponent takes 5 damage!")
            oppHealth -= 5
        elif attack == 'electricity':
            print("You both damage each other!")
            health -= 5
            oppHealth -= 5
        elif attack == 'ice':
            print("Fire beats ice! You take 5 damage!")
            health -= 5
        else:
            print("Invalid attack choice") 

        time.sleep(3)

    if health <= 0 and oppHealth <= 0:
        print("Draw!")
    if health <= 0:
        print("You lose")
    else:
        print("You win!")

startBattle()
```

Though I'd also get rid of all the `sleep`s.  People don't enjoy waiting for a program to "do work" as much as you might think, it's just gonna cause people to click away.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have previously tried making the expressions "health = health - 5" and so forth (should have mentioned that): it doesn't make any difference. I've just now tried adding the global definitions within the function as well, and they also don't change anything.

Comment: @Chromashadow It's because you're not changing the `playStr` and `oppStr` variables to reflect the new values, but if you use the `print`s I've shown, this will fix the problem.  `print("Your health is {0}.".format(health))`

Comment: @Chromashadow you should be asking a question on how to best reason about fire beats ice but loses to water and is even with electricity but does nothing against itself.  I suggest a matrix!

Answer (score 0):

Read a bit more about Python syntax. The correct way to change the value of a variable is, for example:

```
health = health - 5
```

Answer (score 0):

`oppHealth - 5` should be written as

`oppHealth = oppHealth - 5`

You're forgetting save the result of your computation